# Show/hide to work as accordian

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I am trying to run the code to click the link and open the div. If I click the other link, the above link should get closed. The clicked one should one.

I cannot use jquery or anyting else except javascript or dojo. I do not know dojo, but javascript.

I am trying it like this:

```
<ul id="sm">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('s');">abc</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('sa');">xyz</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('ss');">def</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('sd');">efg</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('sfd');">Ter</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Code I am using

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = ((e.style.display!='none') ? 'none' : 'block');
}
```

Providing Div's as:

```
<div id="s" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="sa" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="ss" style="display:none"></div>
```

they are overlapping once i click them

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use jQuery? Because this would be incredibly easy with jQuery.

Comment: What div's? What problems are you having? Where is the actual question?

Comment: jquery is not supported by client, he wants to use either dojo or javascript plain

Comment: edited the question to add the divs

Comment: Okay, you've added the divs, but where are the divs in relation to the code for the line items?

Comment: You need to hide all the other divs. Your only updating the one associated with the clicked one and not *"the above link should get closed"*

Comment: the onclick function is calling the javascript function and element is getting passed to toggle it

Comment: overlapping seems to be an issue of CSS

Comment: so what seems to the solution

Comment: wow -4 for asking a question, that's greata, whoever did it, That is awesome

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try following example. I hope it will help you.....:)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.head {
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    padding:3px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.content {
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:100px;
    padding:3px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideShoowTab(ctb) {
    var ptb = document.getElementById("ptbname").value
    if(document.getElementById("ptbname").value=="") {
        document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
    }
    else if(ptb==ctb) {
        if(document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display=="block") {
            document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("content"+ptb).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("content"+ctb).style.display="block";
    }
    document.getElementById("ptbname").value=ctb;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="head1" class="head" onclick="hideShoowTab('1')">Head 1</div>
        <div id="content1" class="content">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="head2" class="head" onclick="hideShoowTab('2')">Head 2</div>
        <div id="content2" class="content" style="display:none;">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="head3" class="head" onclick="hideShoowTab('3')">Head 3</div>
        <div id="content3" class="content" style="display:none;">Content 3</div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="ptbname" name="ptbname" value="1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't tested your answer, but could you provide some explanations as to **why** this works? (Assuming it does). Code is only useful if it is understood.

Comment: It is very easy to understand above example. You just note every div id, parameter which is passed while calling javascript function on onclick event and also note javascript function logic. To test above example, just copy code and pest it in blank notepad and then save the file with .html extention and run it in any browser.

Comment: I am well aware of how to test said code and my request was not for me, but was in order to follow the site's guidelines.  For example, see this post by Jon Skeet (one of this site's foremost users): http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx Note especially this line: "Code without an explanation is rarely useful, however. At least provide a sentence or two to explain what's going on."

Comment: Ok, thanks  Avery. I understood it and try to follow your suggestion.